# Two PWA under the same domain

Tags: javascript, css, image, scope, progressive-web-apps

I have two PWA (app1 and app2) under the same domain.
Here the directory structure:

```
www.company.com
  js
  css
  images
  app1
       html
  app2
       html
```

The scope of app1 is "www.company.com/app1" and the scope of app2 is "www.company.com/app2".
Under "js", "css" and "images" I have javascript, css and images.

app1 and app2 use "js", "css" and "images".
All seems to be ok.

Question:
Since "js", "css" and "images" are outside the scope should I expect problems or is it allow ?

Thanks
Miche

Answer (score 0):

If app1 and app2 both use the same files (not just the folder) I don't see a problem. You can call your files from root, like `/js/main.js`, in both your apps.

If app1 uses `/js/main-app1.js` and app2 uses `/js/main-app2.js` I would suggest you put a js folder under the app itself like `/app1/js/main-app1.js`. The reason for this it hat it is less confusing for you or other developers in the long run.

You could do both as well - in root for shared libraries (like jquery or lodash), in the folder for app-specific JS.

Comment: I'd like to add that I personally would put the js/img/css folder not directly in root, but in a folder called 'assets', so `/assets/js`, `/assets/css` and `/assets/images`